# GROUP BY and SUM but split the GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql

Dataset:

```
User    Internal Hours   External Hours   Date
Dave         9               0           2020-11-01
Joe          1               0           2020-11-01
Joe          1               0           2020-11-02
Chris        2               0           2020-11-01
Joe          3               0           2020-11-03
Chris        2               0           2020-11-02
Chris        0               0           2020-11-03
Dave         3               0           2020-11-02
Joe          5               0           2020-11-03
Chris        0               3           2020-11-03
Chris        0               1           2020-11-01
Dave         0               1           2020-11-01
Joe          0               2           2020-11-01
Joe          0               4           2020-11-02
Joe          0               2           2020-11-03
Chris        0               3           2020-11-02
Chris        0               3           2020-11-03
Dave         0               1           2020-11-03
```

A Simple:

```
SELECT
    User,
    Date
    SUM(External)
    SUMInternal)
FROM table
GROUP BY User,Date
```

returns:

```
User   Date      Internal Hours   External Hours
Dave  2020-11-01    12              1          
Dave  2020-11-01    0               1           
Joe   2020-11-01    1               4          
Joe   2020-11-02    1               5           
Chris 2020-11-02    2               6           
Chris 2020-11-03    2               6
```

or somethgin equivilent (its really hard to figure out what is actually summing up from my data, but there are always 2 instances per user and everything appears to be summed up under only 2 dates)

What I am AFTER however is:

```
User   Date      Internal Hours   External Hours
Dave  2020-11-01    9               1          
Dave  2020-11-02    3               0           
Dave  2020-11-03    0               1   
Joe   2020-11-01    1               2          
Joe   2020-11-02    1               4       
Joe   2020-11-03    3               2          
Chris 2020-11-01    2               1           
Chris 2020-11-02    2               3          
Chris 2020-11-03    0               3
```

With one ressult table with a line for each date, per user and everything summed up correctly

I've tried inner joins, left joins, cross joins, internal selects and none are working or take longer than 5min to process (its over 135,000 records).

I know there is a obvious way I am missing and I do not want to brute force it with sub selects and have this daily report take multiple hours.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your query looks correct (aside from some syntax errors): `SELECT User, Date, SUM(External), SUM(Internal) ...` In order to help debug further, could you create a test table and add some sample data to https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and share the link to that example? See "Help others reproduce the problem" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, I missed out the commas. The full script contans a lot of sentitive user information so I had to more represent the problem via psuedo code and dummy tables rather than a simple copy/paste.

Thank you for your feedback butthe below comment put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    User,
    `Date`,
    COALESCE(SUM(External), 0),
    COALESCE(SUM(Internal), 0)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT User FROM test) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `Date` FROM test) t2
LEFT JOIN test USING (User, `Date`)
GROUP BY User, `Date`
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f55a7bc08dc800241817fc8f394be4e8)

Cross-joined subqueries generates all possible pairs User-Data. Even this pair is absent in data it will present in output.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is exactly what I needed; I was working with the crossjoins on the sums rather than the user/date fields.the other way around it works now and only 200s :)

Answer (score 0):

I created your same data scenario in my MySQL database.  Having column names by the same name as reserved words is never a good thing.  You could resolve by using `backTicks`, or by using the table, or aliasing the table to qualify.  Your posted sample was also incorrect even if by accident of missing comma and open parenthesis.

```
SELECT
      t1.User,
      t1.Date,
      SUM(t1.External),
      SUM(t1.Internal)
   FROM 
      table1 t1
   GROUP BY 
      t1.User, 
      t1.Date
   order BY 
      t1.User, 
      t1.Date;
```

Got the results per proper date

```
User    Date         SUM(t1.External)  SUM(t1.Internal)
Chris   2020-11-01   1                 2
Chris   2020-11-02   3                 2
Chris   2020-11-03   6                 0
Dave    2020-11-01   1                 9
Dave    2020-11-02   0                 3
Dave    2020-11-03   1                 0
Joe     2020-11-01   2                 1
Joe     2020-11-02   4                 1
Joe     2020-11-03   2                 8
```